# How to disable a specific button out of many button after click?

Tags: javascript, django

I have list of many users.

I have table to display user name and then one input field for email id and then submit button,
when I enter email id of a specific user and click submit then user get userid and password in their mailbox.

I want when I submit the submit button of that particular user get disabled.

I am using Django for loop in html so its disables submit button of all users.

I want only that users button get disables.

```
<a id="elementId" href="{% url 'urlabc' %}" onclick="setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('elementId').this.removeAttribute('href');}, 1);">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

Add a `BooleanField` in your model and set its default value to `False`.

```py
class YourModel(models.Model):
    email_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In the template use this field to disable or enable each link.

```html
{% for user in users %}
    <a href="{% url 'urlabc' %}" onclick="return !{{ user.email_sent }};">Click</a>
{% endfor %}
```

when you send an email set `email_sent` of the user's model to `True` and the link will be disabled.

Note: There won't be any visual cue that shows the link as being disabled but you could use the boolean to style or set attributes of the link or a button to be disabled visually.